# How would I hold down a click keystroke in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am having a problem when using my AHK script.

I want to hold down the left click for 13 seconds.

```
Click down
Sleep, 13000
Click up
```

It works on Google Chrome when I am clicking on text and I drag my mouse it highlights (meaning of course it is clicking down).

When I go on my game it wont click anything.

Am I doing it wrong or is it a problem with AutoHotKey?

Answer (score 1):

See [SendPlay](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendPlayDetail) docs:

> SendPlay's biggest advantage is its ability to "play back" keystrokes and mouse clicks in a broader variety of games than the other modes.

```
SendPlay {LButton down}
sleep 13000
SendPlay {LButton up}
```

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, I often find that running my scripts as administrator helps solve most of my problems when scripting for games, especially if the game itself is ran on administrator levels.